# When and when not to decode or encode JSON between API endpoints

Tags: javascript, php, netsuite, restlet, suitescript2.0

Custom PHP integration from a linux server to a javascript API. I am the developer on both ends. Typical web app connection to a business software. Sending JSON payloads from PHP to Javascript API (Suitescript), and parsing the response back.

Test data set
{'result': 'success', 'data': {'test': 'test'}}

My test
PHP 7.2 sends a Curl POST request with a JSON encoded payload using json_encode(). The request is signed using hmac-sha256.

Javascript endpoint (Netsuite RESTlet) receives the request. Request is decoded using javascript JSON.parse(). It works as expected.

The javascript API returns the same JSON object using JSON.stringify().

The problem
The PHP script that sent the request decodes the JSON string, but into a string. print_r() shows the json as a string and gettype() returns string.

I have determined this is because of
JSON.stringify({'result': 'success', 'data': {'test': 'test'}})
in the javascript API return function.

If I remove the JSON.stringify(), then PHP is able to decode the response into an Array.
I don't understand this behavior. I use a similar technique in Python, and it works as expected. The official Netsuite documentation also reflects using JSON.stringify() when returning results.

What is best practice?

Comment: *stringify* to transmit (request or response) - *parse* on receive (unless that part is done for you)

Comment: Given the fact the json you've shown doesn't actually represent an array, is there any reason not to think that PHP is messing it up when you 'forget' to `JSON.stringify` before sending?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're using `JSON.stringify()` on the original string received from PHP when you should be using it on the object returned by `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

RESTlets are a bit odd in that you control the output content-type by setting the input content-type. You may need to explicitly set the *request's* `Content-Type` to `application/json` in order to see consistent results.

Then your RESTlet code should just return an object and Netsuite will convert that to JSON. You should not return the result of `JSON.stringify()`.